# JMS Destination on remote server

Tags: java, jboss, jms, weblogic

I'm using Weblogic 8.1. and other server is using JBoss 5.0. My plan is to have the JNDI destination of weblogic to be consumed on JBoss 5.0 using MDBs. I think it is possible, but not sure. If so, how can I achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples out there on how to do this, assuming for instance you want weblogic to consume JMS messages generated by JBoss, you can set up a Foreign JMS Server. In the admin console:

```
Jms Modules -> New -> Choose Targets -> Click the box to add resources -> Next
New -> Foreign Server
Jms Modules -> YourModule -> YourForeignServer -> Use the config tab set up URL info
```

You can follow an example here for [JBoss](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6066) or [ActiveMQ](http://amadei.com.br/blog/index.php/connecting-weblogic-and-activemq)

Going in reverse, receiving JMS messages from Weblogic on the JBoss side.... a very similar thing can be done. You will probably want to write your own class to communicate with foreign JNDI objects. There is a good info in the JBoss docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r5/html/ch6.chapt.html). Specifically pay attention to the notes at the end on what class to replace.

You can also see a similar setup [Integrating Weblogic 8 JMS with JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/IntegratingWeblogic81JMSwithJboss51)